# Recover Ubuntu Environment on Windows after windows reset

Tags: windows, data-recovery, reset

I am (and was) using WSL and MobaXterm to create a Linux Dev environment on Windows. After being stuck in an Automatic Repair loop that did not allow me neither remove the last updates in my system or access to it in safe mode, I reset my PC, maintaining all my local data intact (although some apps were uninstalled).
I recovered everything easily except for my Ubuntu environment, which contained some important data.

Is there any way to recover the information in my Ubuntu environment? or it has been all removed from my PC?

Best,
Pedro.

Comment: I try to keep all my WSL files on the Windows file system, for example a subdirectory of `/mnt/c/Users/Mark`.  Then you always have two ways to access it.

Answer (score 7):

This is more a windows related answer but... look inside :

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\[distro name]
```

If inside there's a file named `ext4.vhdx` you still have the virtual disk image of ubuntu, otherwise It's gone.

Comment: If you find this file, is there a way to copy it somewhere else and mount it once you reinstall WSL?

Comment: Theoretically you can copy the ext4.vhdx. 
Reinstall the same distro that you had before and replace the new ext4.vhdx with the old one.